# Tensorboard doesnt log data if script is terminated shortly after

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorboard

Following the [pytorch tensorboard tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/tensorboard_tutorial.html) I noticed that my images wherent logged to tensorboard. This problem resolved when I added some extra lines after the line where I write the images.
Does anyone know a solution that actually fixes this issue?

```py
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter


transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))
])

trainset = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST('./datasets/data/',
    download=True,
    train=True,
    transform=transform
)

trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4, shuffle=True)

data_iter = iter(trainloader)
images, labels = data_iter.next()

img_grid = torchvision.utils.make_grid(images)

# define a tensorboard writer
writer = SummaryWriter("runs/demo_1_fashion_mnist")
writer.add_image("four_fashion_mnist_images", img_grid)

# without loop images wont be logged
while True:
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding `writer.close()` as last line, the images will be logged correctly.